# Re-organize meals in a 32-hour day?

Tags: culture, space-colonization

The idea of adapting to a longer day is not new.  Besides other recent questions here, I recall it in [*When Worlds Collide* (or its sequel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_Worlds_Collide).

As I'm rewarming half a pizza for a *late* meal, I wonder how society will change in this specific manner?

What do you **call** the different meals? What traditions and workflow will develop around this biological anchor?

---

**example:** Lunch is made intentionally to have leftovers. Dinner is a big social time and gathering. Then late meal will quickly grab the reserved portion from lunch. So what is it called?

If you don't have left-lunch prepared, you'll just grab junkfood instead. So it became important to plan this, but not take more time away for cooking.  **How will people naturally organize their longer wake periods around such biological anchors and cultural inertia?**

Comment: I feel this necessary, even if not related: http://askmiddlearth.tumblr.com/post/41765286488/the-seven-daily-hobbit-meals

Comment: Different cultures think of meals differently, even across time. In Portugal, for example, every meal is rife for social gathering, making most of them potentially long. These days breakfast is at 7-8, lunch is at 12 or 1pm and dinner at 8, while supper is almost unheard of; 50 years ago, field workers had milk and coffee for breakfast at the break of dawn, lunch at 9am, dinner at 3 or 4 and supper at 8 or 9. I think work schedules and religious demands are the main factors shaping a culture's approach to meals.

Comment: Even withing cultures, different people have different work schedules which dictate when they are free to eat. Someone working a 10pm-6am nightshift will probably eat a light breakfast at the time when others would be eating a large family dinner.

Comment: True, shift work always peturbs the basic cultural norm.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, there are different traditions for different countries. In my experience, Brits and Canadians seem to have a lighter lunch and a more consistent breakfast and dinner than in France. The time people eat also varies from household to household. Some people take their meals with clockwork precision, some have a couple hours window.

I don't see a reason these differences would disappear. So the answer will vary from culture to culture, and from person to person.

---

For organizing meals, I see two ways of going about it.

You first option is to keep as many meals as we have. The key difference is that they'll be further apart, so logically you'll be active longer between meals, so you'll need to eat slightly more.

Your second option is to get a new meal. Keep breakfast and lunch were they are, push dinner further, and add a meal between lunch and dinner. There happens to be a word for mid-afternoon snacking, [nuncheon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuncheon). Lunch and dinner may become slightly lighter meals, or they may not. It'll depend on how much you eat at nuncheon.

You shouldn't worry too much about the time it takes to cook. Your day will be longer, so it stands to reason you'll have a bit more free time to do it.

A side issue may be for people who fast based on the sun being up, like Muslims during Ramadan. If we're taking about planets that can have the sun rise and set several time during a standard day, it'll make for really unorthodox meal times. Aside from that, it should only change how much they eat.