# How much would we sleep if a day was 36 hours-long? How would eating habits and general work hours change?

Tags: biology, humans, day-night

What would happen to our sleep habits if a day was 36 hours-long instead of 24 hours?

Would we sleep twice a day or would be there one longer sleep?

How would the daily routine differ in terms of *work hours*, *sleep periods* and *eating habits*?

Comment: See also [meals in a 32 hour day](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45240/re-organize-meals-in-a-32-hour-day) for one specific issue.

Comment: Been seeing lots of stories to indicate our current eight hour sleep pattern is abnormal, and a bi-modal, or poly-modal, pattern is what we are adapted to. (bright electric light messing with normal rhythms)

Comment: @Molot that one is pretty specific in its timeline, and not the same as this one. Doesn't seem like a duplicate. However, I am voting it closed as too broad. GorkemHalulu, you should edit the question to specify some parts of the daily routine you want to address, or just ask the second question and nominate for reopening. Alos, we need background on whether these are humans or aliens that are native to this 36 hour world to answer.

Comment: @kingledion I edited my question to norrow down daily routine. I guess it is more specific now. Actually, I was also wondering about other considerations but it will be also fine to hear about these specific parts :)

Comment: Since this question was locked, maybe someday, if you yet need it, you'll post a new one with more information necessary for people to give answers.  This one does indeed ask too much:  we don't know what other environmental stressors are present, for starters.

Answer (score 4):

36 hours is not too much for humans to adapt to it. Our circadian clock responds to the ambient light. Without 24-hour days, there would be little that attaches us to this schedule, moreover, trying to establish a day circle that is different from the natural light circle would cause disorders in our bodies.

People who spend long time without sunlight (for example in caves) are developing their own cycles, typically longer than 24-hour.

See also this Wikipedia article: [Non-24-hour sleep–wake disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-24-hour_sleep%E2%80%93wake_disorder).